# Random numbers with orders less than E-1

Tags: python, random, montecarlo, uniform-distribution

I'm currently working on a kinetic Monte Carlo simulation in **Python**, so I need to generate pseudo-random numbers between 0 and 1 that follow the uniform distribution, but I'm searching to obtain at some point numbers less than E-1, for example, 0.001. I know that it won't be common, because they are random numbers after all, but my problem started in the implementation of Monte Carlo.

The problem in my Monte Carlo simulation, briefly is, I have one *constraint_probability=c* and one *pseudo-random number=r*, but because of the dynamics of my problem, I have the condition that my code only run if *r < c*. If I make for example *c=0.001*, my code never run.

My first thought was to use `random.uniform`, but I found that the numbers obtained were at least with an order of E-2.

Later, I thought that my problem could be solved by making the following function:

```
from scipy.stats import uniform


def numrand():
        vec=np.linspace(uniform.ppf(0),uniform.ppf(1), 10000) 
        return random.choice(vec)
```

I don't know if it's possible to obtain random numbers less than E-1 or if is another way to make my code run.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking here.  Once you state that the random numbers are uniform between 0 and 1, uniformity means they are equally likely to be any outcome between 0 and 1, and only 1 in 10 of them on average will be below E-1.  If you would describe what you want to accomplish in your Monte Carlo sim it might help the rest of us better understand your question.  By the way, an old programmer's maxim says that correctness comes first, then you can worry about optimization.

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.random](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html) can likely help you here, to create 10000 random numbers between 0 and 1 with uniform distribution you can use

```py
np.random.default_rng().uniform(0, 1, 10000)
```

or for older numpy versions:

```
np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `np.random.uniform` the [max and min value that you want](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html). Since you seem to want numbers of the order ~10<sup>-5</sup>, ask for `min=1e-5` and `max=1e-4`:

```
vec = np.random.uniform(1e-5, 1e-4, 10000)
assert (vec >= 1e-5).all() and (vec < 1e-4).all()
```

Since samples are uniformly distributed over the half-open interval `[min, max)`, you can rest assured that any number you get from the distribution will be of the order 10<sup>-5</sup>

This should also work with other distributions.